# Excel 2010 does not recognize vbTab as tab delimeters

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript

I would like a return CSV file from a WebPage using VBScript.

Here is the code

```
Response.Write rsTest.Fields("FieldName1") & vbTab
Response.Write rsTest.Fields("FieldName2") & vbTab
Response.Write vbCrLf
```

However, when i opened the downloaded CSV file. Excel 2010 does not recognize vbTab as tab delimiters.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question? What error message do you get?

Comment: When i open the CSV file in Excel, it does not recognize the tab, something like "FieldName1FieldName2", but i open it in Notepad++, then the tab is recognized "FieldName1 FieldName2". Do you have any idea why excel does not recognize the tab in this case ? Thanks

Comment: If you drag and drop the csv file into excel, excel will show the import settings it uses. if the tab character is not the default separator, which it isn´t, it won´t work. You can verify that by selecting tab as the field delim in this dialog -- then, the import will work.

Comment: That´s why I use ";" as the separator in .csv files. Such files can be double-clicked and then open an excel document with the data shown correctly (as long as field values containing a ";" are quoted in double quotes).